# Android Loading to cursor an id range

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id,name FROM  people WHERE id="+ id + " AND name IS NULL",null);
```

Instead of loading only one id's record to my cursor, I want to load a range of id such as starting id=100 to id=150 to the cursor. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by changing the operators used in your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT id, name FROM  people WHERE id>100 AND id<150 AND name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Try these query

```
SELECT id, name FROM  people WHERE id >= 100 AND id <= 150 AND name IS NULL
SELECT id, name FROM  people WHERE id BETWEEN 100 AND 150 AND name IS NULL
```

Comment: for the second query the limits values are including or not ? I mean the records 100 and 150 are including to cursor ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id,name FROM  people WHERE id <"+ upperBoundId + " AND id > " + lowerBoundId" + AND name IS NULL",null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select id,name from people where id>100 and id<150 and name is null",null);
int Column1 = c.getColumnIndex("id");
int Column2 = c.getColumnIndex("name");
c.moveToFirst();
   if (c != null) {
    // Loop through all Results
    do {
         int id = c.getInt(Column1);
     String name = c.getString(Column2);

    }while(c.moveToNext());
```